# Using CYPRESS PSOC4 controller SPI -No sync between data and clock

Tags: spi, embedded

In SPI, CPHA and POL is 0, probed on clock and MOSI line, seeing data transition in when the clock is not available. Or there is sync between clock and data line.

[image]

Comment: Where's the problem? If the last bit of the last word is different to the 1st bit of the next word, then the data line needs to change before the clock.

Comment: in Second-byte data line is going high to low,but the clock is not available

Comment: What do you mean by "the clock is not available"? Why do you think it matters how long before the clock pulse the data line changes?

Comment: Yeah, I understood.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of the data starts at the edge of STROBE (CE). So, if you time/probe the signals along with the strobe, you will feel it just right.